# Discord bot showing member number in the channel name

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

this is the code I have so far:

```js
    setInterval(function () {
    let myGuild = client.guilds.cache.get("0000000000000");
    let memberNumber = myGuild.members.cache.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size;

    }, 1000);
```

And as you can probably tell here, I have successfully managed to create a Discord bot to count the number of members on my server, bots not included, and have that be checked every one second in Discord.JS.
What I don't know what to do is have that number show in a channel name and have it constantly updated, the way the 'ServerStats' Discord bot does it. (like have the channel name Members: 1, and have the number updated when the memberCount increases or decreases, I will have a photo of the example). Could you show me how to do it and explain what you did in a lot of detail, but at a noob level, as I am very new to coding?

[image: Category is 'Server Stats' and the channel name is: 'Members: 118', and is constantly being updated]

Answer (score 2):

First off, it may just be easier to run it in the guildMemberAdd event instead of updating it every second so you don't spam the API.

This is probably more what you want:

```
client.on("guildMemberAdd", function(member){
    let myGuild = member.guild
    let myChannel = myGuild.channels.cache.get("CHANNEL ID HERE");
    let memberNumber = myGuild.members.cache.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size;
    myChannel.name = `Members: ${memberNumber}`
})
```

Comment: How often would this be updated, if you can explain the code a little bit, is it just every time a new member is added?

Comment: It is updated every time a member joins. I also forgot to mention it would probably be best to add the same code to the guildMemberRemove event so that it updates when members leave too

Comment: I keep getting this error: events.js:131
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('listener', 'Function', listener); at this line:  let memberNumber = myGuild.members.cache.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size;

Comment: > events.js:131
Are you storing all your events here?
Why not have them separated?